# How to create a new URL Mapping in websphere portal?

Tags: websphere-portal

What are the steps to create a new URL mapping in websphere portal 6.1. I have a portlet (UserPortlet) and I want to map it to a label (e.g. UserPortletLabel).

So I go to Manage Pages, create a new label called UserPortletLabel and then go to the URL Mapping tab. Now I expect to see the label that I jsut created so I can map it to my portlet. But the UserPortletLabel does not show up in the list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to archieve. Do you want to create a page that is reachable under: http://yourserver.com/wps/portal/UserPortletLabel or do you want to create a shortcut to an existing page?

Comment: Yes..create a page reachable under /wps/portal/UserPortletLabel

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instructions (with WebSphere Portal 7 though) and the label showed up. In case its not showing up you should probably open up ab PMR with IBM support.

If you just need a reliable path to your page you can use the friendly url on each page/label.